# User authentication using Laravel 5.4 API and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, rest, api, vue.js

I've created an API using Laravel 5.4 which provides me a token after logging in. So, in Vue.js project I've created an `auth` folder and an `index.js` file in it, so that it can be reusable.

**Here's my `auth/index.js` file:**

```
import router from '../router'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    user: {
        authenticated: false
    },

    login(context, credentials, redirect) {
        axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/login', credentials)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                if(response.data.success) {
                    localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.token)

                    this.user.authenticated = true;
                    router.go('/');
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                context.error = error;
            });
    }
}
```

**Here's `login()` method in my `Login.vue` component:**

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import auth from '../../auth/'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            credentials: {
                login: '',
                password: ''
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        login() {
            auth.login(this, this.credentials, 'admin/dashboard');
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I have a trouble in redirecting to my route after saving an `access_token` to the `localStorage`. The page is just being refreshed and that's all. What's a workaround?

Comment: Are you using vue 2.0 or higher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`router.go()` changed in **VueJS 2.0**.

You can use `router.push({ name: "routerName"})` or just `router.push("routerName")` now to redirect.

Check the docs: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html

Comment: Thanks it helped..)